# error: could not lock config file C:/SPB_Data/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github

I just installed git on window 7. I dont know much about git that's why taking course from https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-git-github. After getting installed we configure our git user name and email by the following command:

```
$ git config --global user.name "your name"
$ git config --global user.email "your email"
```

but every time I get an error states that:

**error: could not lock config file C:/SPB_Data/.gitconfig: No such file or directory**

why isn't it working. I also watch some youtube videos and it works for other people very well.

Comment: Try to create `C:/SPB_Data/.gitconfig` with other methods first.

Comment: @ElpieKay but .gitconfig file is already present but not in the mention directory instead it is present in `D:\Git\etc`

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar issue. Also couldn't use `git clone`. What appears to be an issue is a corrupted `HOME` environment variable.
To fix this, set `HOME` environment variable for your user to `C:\Users\<your_username>`. This can be done using the **PowerShell**:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HOME", "C:\Users\<your_username>", "User")`

or alternatively, you can use UI to set it. [Instructions are HERE](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable)

After setting the environment variable you should be able to use git to its fullest. You would need to restart your terminal.

**[EDIT]** This was most likely caused by installing some of the `Cadence` software. [Source.](https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/pcb-design/f/pcb-design/38719/how-to-remove-delete-the-pre-existing-home-path-and-point-it-to-new-location)

Comment: Thanks. Also found my $HOME set to "/c/SPB_Data" after I installed CadencePCBViewer.  What kind of software does this? 

Answer (score 1):

Making the configurations locally for every repository you work on can be a workaround.

```
$ git config user.name "your name"
$ git config user.email "your email"
```